# JSON Response to a List collection or Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am struggling to figure out why my `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is returning back Null. From what I understand, everything seems to be correct and I can see the Json response from `GetStringAsync(myURL)`.

Property class was made through QuickType (also tried directly through Visual Studio Paste from Json class creator).

My property Class:

```
public partial class MoversRoot
{
    List<Movers> getMovers { get; set; }
}
public partial class Movers
{
    [JsonProperty("change")]
    public long Change { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("direction")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last")]
    public long Last { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalVolume")]
    public long TotalVolume { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my code that uses an instance of HttpClient to GetStringAsync - `getData` in debug shows my Json response as it should. here is the screenshot of the Json through inspector.
[image]

However my `var movers` is Null when debugging. I've tried various ways and my movers var always ends up being null. where did I go wrong?

```
string myURL = new Uri(@"https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/$SPX.X/movers?apikey=" + token).ToString();          

            var getData = await HttpClientInstance.Instance.GetStringAsync(myURL);

            var movers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MoversRoot>(getData);
```

Json String (per request):

```
[{"change":-0.043154387156591506,"description":"IPG Photonics Corporation - Common Stock","direction":"down","last":149.0,"symbol":"IPGP","totalVolume":473896},{"change":-0.04596881645392344,"description":"Electronic Arts Inc. - Common Stock","direction":"down","last":93.6,"symbol":"EA","totalVolume":11794145},{"change":-0.028465181202540747,"description":"Rockwell Automation, Inc. Common Stock","direction":"down","last":159.39,"symbol":"ROK","totalVolume":1047335},{"change":-0.003665714227582914,"description":"Apache Corporation Common Stock","direction":"down","last":27.18,"symbol":"APA","totalVolume":8024082},{"change":-0.02684707330738466,"description":"Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated - Common Stock","direction":"down","last":178.34,"symbol":"VRTX","totalVolume":878875},{"change":-0.030052397132803322,"description":"Nektar Therapeutics - Common Stock","direction":"down","last":35.18,"symbol":"NKTR","totalVolume":1092229},{"change":-0.03420337996611522,"description":"Regeneron Pharmaceuticals, Inc. - Common Stock","direction":"down","last":307.5,"symbol":"REGN","totalVolume":799579},{"change":-0.022643827976298412,"description":"PulteGroup, Inc. Common Stock","direction":"down","last":31.94,"symbol":"PHM","totalVolume":3248470},{"change":-0.0190979519989881,"description":"Lennar Corporation Class A Common Stock","direction":"down","last":48.28,"symbol":"LEN","totalVolume":2755112},{"change":-0.019616651726126987,"description":"D.R. Horton, Inc. Common Stock","direction":"down","last":43.48,"symbol":"DHI","totalVolume":2445152},{"change":0.023360000000000013,"description":"Nordstrom, Inc. Common Stock","direction":"up","last":31.98,"symbol":"JWN","totalVolume":2602701},{"change":0.03426644354123586,"description":"Jefferies Financial Group Inc. Common Stock","direction":"up","last":21.43,"symbol":"JEF","totalVolume":3845367},{"change":0.021359204387494307,"description":"Foot Locker, Inc.","direction":"up","last":42.08,"symbol":"FL","totalVolume":3363962},{"change":0.02491751783290532,"description":"L Brands, Inc.","direction":"up","last":27.97,"symbol":"LB","totalVolume":4316848},{"change":0.020912577144276984,"description":"Diamondback Energy, Inc. - Commmon Stock","direction":"up","last":107.4,"symbol":"FANG","totalVolume":1356003},{"change":0.018514460830743065,"description":"Zions Bancorporation N.A. - Common Stock","direction":"up","last":46.21,"symbol":"ZION","totalVolume":1456836},{"change":0.017426412722251497,"description":"Comerica Incorporated Common Stock","direction":"up","last":72.98,"symbol":"CMA","totalVolume":1384308},{"change":0.01433982456706795,"description":"M&T Bank Corporation Common Stock","direction":"up","last":174.01,"symbol":"MTB","totalVolume":598406},{"change":0.0173953706757574,"description":"Macy's Inc Common Stock","direction":"up","last":21.64,"symbol":"M","totalVolume":5873615},{"change":0.018309164170755843,"description":"SunTrust Banks, Inc. Common Stock","direction":"up","last":63.96,"symbol":"STI","totalVolume":1821190}]
```

Comment: Looking at the JSON structure, you could deserialize it with `var movers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movers>>(getData);` or an array (`Movers[]`) instead of a List. Or `var movers = JArray.Parse(getData);`. But you should post the actual JSON string.

Comment: @Jimi Just updated my post with the json string. Also I tried with List<Movers> and also Movers[] as an array which yield same results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Works for me. I modified the type of `Change` and `Last` properties, because those are `double`, not `long` and `var movers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movers>>(getData);` works as expected with the JSON you posted. `List<Movers>`, not `List<MoversRoot>` or `MoversRoot`. `Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1`.

Comment: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fPolPJ) of the results.

Comment: @Jimi well crap :( all this time I'm fiddling with the code itself and ignored the types completely becauase I trusted Visual Studio Json to class converter or Json2class / QuickType to do the work properly creating property classes. I appreciate you taking the time to review the code. You should have posted your answer for acceptance. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```cs
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MoversRoot>(getData);
```

with

```cs
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movers>>(data);
```

and change the long property to double

Comment: Thanks! Jimi answered with same response. I tested and works fine. I have another Json with what looks to be a parent/root attribute I had trouble with. I'll post it here if you could walk me through proper class setup for root attribute that is also a collection of sub attributes.